# How to use BoofCV in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, boofcv

How can I import BoofCV in my Android Studio project? I have already looked [here](http://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Download). I am totally confused. Please provide me a step by step guide. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the line below to app/build.gradle should do the trick

```
compile group: 'org.boofcv', name: 'android', version: '0.23'
```

Replace 0.23 with whatever is the current version.

UPDATE
In more recent versions you need to do the following instead:

```
api group: 'org.boofcv', name: 'boofcv-android', version: '0.30'
```

Comment: It worked. Can you help me in that [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018558/boofcv-android-detect-hand-gestures) related to BoofCV?

Comment: using version 0.34, note that you should target api 26 minimum. otherwise, you will get some dex exceptions

Answer (score 1):

When Integrating BoofCV in Android Studio I faced some issues. I am posting those and its solutions here, so that it will be useful for others.

**BoofCV Android Support Integration Document Link**
https://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Android_support

**Adding BoofCV in Android Studio**

If you are going to use only one module you can add the following code to app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    api group: 'org.boofcv', name: 'boofcv-android', version: '0.34'
}
```

If you are going to use more than one module you can add the following code to app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ['boofcv-android', 'boofcv-core'].each { String a -> api group: 'org.boofcv', name: a, version: '0.34' }
}
```

**Conflicts with Android dependencies**

If you are getting conflicts error you need to add the following in app/build.gradle

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: "xmlpull", module: "xmlpull"
    all*.exclude group: "org.apache.commons", module: "commons-compress"
    all*.exclude group: "com.thoughtworks.xstream", module: "commons-compress"
}
```

**Failure Verifying Dex Error**

If you get failure to verify dex file bad method handle type 7 then you need to add the following in app/build.gradle

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that tried this and still couldn't use Boofcv.

It is important to also add

```
dependencies {
     api group: 'org.boofcv', name: 'boofcv-core', version: '0.31'
}
```

I know it sounds kinda obvious, but I didn't find anything that said I explicitly needed to do that. Good luck!